spring boot micrometer traceId,spanId not found for console appender pattern
I'm working with a Spring Boot 3.2 application and have configured instrumentation for tracing using Micrometer and OpenTelemetry. Here's my setup:
Dependencies:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-otlp</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-logback-appender-1.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.0-alpha</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-instrumentation-api-semconv</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.0-alpha</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
        </dependency>

logback-spring.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>

    <springProperty scope="context" name="application_name" source="spring.application.name"/>

    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
              value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>

    <appender name="flatConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <appender name="OPEN_TELEMETRY"
              class="io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.logback.appender.v1_0.OpenTelemetryAppender">
        <captureExperimentalAttributes>true</captureExperimentalAttributes>
        <captureKeyValuePairAttributes>true</captureKeyValuePairAttributes>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="flatConsoleAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="OPEN_TELEMETRY"/>
    </root>
</configuration>

application.properties:
logging.pattern.level=%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]

Problem:
While I see traceId and spanId in the OpenTelemetry logs, they are missing from my console logs. I've configured the logging.pattern.level property to include them, but they aren't appearing.
Question:
Is anything missing from my configuration that would prevent the traceId and spanId from being logged to the console?
